# awk Search for a petern,that is inside a variable, in a file that starts with that pattern

Tags: awk, file-search

I want search for specific pattern, that i have inside a variable, in a file and that pattern must be the starting point of the line to print the line.
I have done it with grep here:

```
grep -n "^"$curdate"" ./file
```

Now i want to do the same with awk. i have done this with awk:

```
awk -v pat="$input" -F ":" '$0~pat{print NR") "$2 }' ./file
```

But the problem with the awk code above is that it prints every line that contains the pattern even if if it finds it in the middle of the line and not ONLY on the start!!

I think the solution is easy but i cannot find the syntax for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, since there are no samples so couldn't test it but should work. Using regexp `^` here which indicates that we are looking for value which starts with in each line.

```
awk -v pat="$input" -F ":" '$0~"^"pat{print NR") "$2 }' ./file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using `index` option of `awk`  try following.

```
awk -v pat="$input" -F ":" 'index($0,pat)==1{print NR") "$2 }'  Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** Using `substr` method of `awk`:

```
awk -v pat="$input" -F ":" 'substr($0,1,length(pat))==var{print NR") "$2 }' Input_file
```

Comment: i have done the first solution and IT WORKED 
thanks a lot

Comment: @Psz_13, Your welcome, glad that it helped you, I added 2 more solutions in case they may help you too, cheers and happy learning on SO.